# How can I find the most time-consuming part of my code?

Tags: julia

How can I estimate the execution time of each segment of my julia code?
I guess in most cases only one or two functions are the most time-consuming parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can profile it with the Profile standard library (https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/profile/) which gives you a quite low-level trace. Visualizing this trace can be done with e.g. https://github.com/timholy/ProfileView.jl or https://github.com/tkluck/StatProfilerHTML.jl.

If you want a more granular view of what takes time you can use a package like https://github.com/KristofferC/TimerOutputs.jl where you can annotate sections in your code and get a table with how much time was spent in each section.

Comment: Do I have to write _@timeit to_ before every function or structure?

Comment: I wrote _@timeit to_ before every function but the execution time of every function is shown in multiple parts. How can I show the total execution time of them?

Comment: put the `@timeit` inside of the function, i.e. wrap the function body in an `@timeit begin ... end` block.